# Page not found when navigating to a numeric page url (blog date folder) in Umbraco 4.7.2

Tags: url, data-structures, blogs, umbraco

Here is my content structure:

```
Root node
- Page
- Blog
- - 2012
- - - 09
- - - - Blog post
```

The root node hostname is **test.local**, Blog folder hostame is **blog.test.local**

Web.config: **umbracoUseDirectoryUrls=true, umbracoHideTopLevelNodeFromPath=true**
umbracoSettings.config: **useDomainPrefixes=true, addTrailingSlash=true**

When navigating to **blog.test.local/2012/** it gives "Page Not Found" error page. However when I go to **test.local/blog/2012/** the page is rendering properly. I understand that Umbraco is trying to load page by ID when getting /2012/ request, but why the node url doesn't have priority? Did I miss enything in configuration?

P.S. If I set **umbracoUseDirectoryUrls=false** blog.test.local/**2012.aspx** is not working either.

umbraco v 4.7.2 (Assembly version: 1.0.4500.21031)

Comment: With this kind of structure, I usually use the urlrewrite.config to point the /yyyy/ and /yyyy/mm/ at my default listing but just filtered by date. I would pass the year or year and month as querystring keys.

Comment: When you say 'Blog folder hostame is blog.test.local', do you mean that you have set that hostname in Umbraco itself on the Blog node?

Comment: I believe this was corrected last year. Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Umbraco. I have submitted a bug report here: 
http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-634
Give it a vote!

And the bug is discussed here:
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/ourumb-dev-forum/bugs/31454-472-breaks-all-URL-paths-that-parse-to-a-number,-like-2012-for-example